# Setting CPView frame so that it encases drawn rect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cappuccino, objective-j

my goal in Cappuccino is to adjust the CPView's frame so that every point of a drawn rect is encased. The rect is rotatable which makes it tricky: 
[image: here]
<sub>(source: [asawicki.info](http://www.asawicki.info/files/aabb_of_rotated_rectangle.png))</sub>
.

I understand that in Cocoa I'd use CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context). 
How would I handle such a problem in Cappuccino?

**Edit**: That's the answer to my problem, based on Alexander's tips:

```
var context = [[CPGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort],
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(CGRectGetWidth([self bounds])/2, CGRectGetHeight([self bounds])/2), rotationRadians);

CGContextBeginPath(context);
path2 = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path2, transform, CGRectMake(-newWidth/2, -newHeight/2, newWidth, newHeight));
CGContextAddPath(context, path2);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextSetFillColor(context, [CPColor yellowColor]);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

var frame = [self frame];
frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth([self bounds]);
frame.size.height =  CGRectGetHeight([self bounds]);
oldFrameWidth = frame.size.width;
oldFrameHeight = frame.size.height;
newFrameWidth = CGRectGetWidth(CGPathGetBoundingBox(path2));
newFrameHeight = CGRectGetHeight(CGPathGetBoundingBox(path2));
frame.size.width = newFrameWidth;
frame.size.height = newFrameHeight;
frame.origin.x -= (newFrameWidth - oldFrameWidth)/2;
frame.origin.y -= (newFrameHeight - oldFrameHeight)/2;
[self setFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myPath` is a CGPath describing your rotated rect, you can get the bounding rectangle using:

```
CGPathGetBoundingBox(myPath)
```

Comment: Alex, I currently have the correct dimensions of the bounding CPView (see code above) but the drawn rect's center is at the top left corner of the CPView. How can I bring it to the center of the CPView?

Comment: That's because you're drawing your rect that way, at (-newWidth/2, -newHeight/2). If you want to draw it in the centre instead you can add translation to your transform of half the bounding width and height.

Comment: Thanks. How can I add the translation to the transform without overwriting the rotation?

Comment: You can "combine" multiple transforms, like this: `transform  = CGAffineTransformTranslate( CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationRadians), newWidth / 2, newHeight / 2))`.

Comment: Thank, with the code above, I don't get much further as the top left corner of the drawn rect just matches the top left corner of the bounding CPView.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow what's wrong with that. Did you not want to place your rectangle inside of your view? If your issue is with the centre point of rotation you can invert the order of the transformation - translate first, then rotate.

Comment: Correct, I had to invert the order of the transformation, thanks! Since a bit longer I have a drawing issue with the code above. The rectangle would not draw every time I change the height or width variables, sporadically it would not show until I slightly change the width/height again. Is that I performance issue? It wasn't the case when I was using CGContextFillRect to create the rect.

Comment: The view should redraw when you change the height/width of it automatically, although it might collect multiple redraw operations into one using the run loop. If you want to cause extra redraws you may use `[view setNeedsDisplay:YES]`.

Comment: The view doesn't redraw automatically, I still need to call `[view setNeedsDisplay:YES]` to do that. I must add that I use a slider to change the height, width and radian variables in the CPView (e.g. calling `-(void)setNewWidth:(float)aNewWidth {
newWidth = aNewWidth;
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}` Do I potentially overstrain `CGPathAddRect`with so many calls?

Comment: When does it not redraw automatically? There is no `setNewWidth:` message for views. You need to call `setFrameSize:` or `setFrame:`.

Comment: A CPWindowController calls this custom method of the view: `- (void)setNewWidth:(float)aNewWidth {
    newWidth = aNewWidth;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}`And the `drawRect:(CGRect)aRect`method has the above edited code.